# Update multiple records with foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel

I use this to update my status field, but it only updates a single record, how can I update multiple records

```
  private function __detalleVenta($idventa = null, $estado = '')
{
    $detalleVenta =  DetalleVenta::where('idventa', $idventa)->firstOrFail();
    $detalleVenta->estado = 'Venta Cobrada';
    $detalleVenta->save();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the query builder `update()` method. it's an update statement in DB. (will also work if no records are affected by it)

Carefull that this bypass any logic you have in your model class (exp: updated_at will not be changed)

```
private function __detalleVenta($idventa = null, $estado = '')
{ 
    DetalleVenta::where('idventa', $idventa)->update(['estado' => 'Venta Cobrada']);
}
```

Comment: private function __detalleVenta($idventa = null, $estado = '')
    {
        $detalleVenta =  DetalleVenta::where('idventa', $idventa)->update(['estado' => 'Venta Cobrada']);
       
        $detalleVenta->save();
    
    }

Comment: @ChristianAldana update the response for more clarity. you should also remove the parameter `$estado = ''`it's not used